# How to resolve the error "Emgu.CV.CvInvoke"?

Tags: c#

[image]

How can I solve the problem? I use an OS 64 bytes.

Comment: Welcome to stackoveflow :) Please update your question to be more friendly. For start, please post your code in your question (please avoid using links, it difficult to go back and forward...Then specify the line in which you hit the wall. In your case the TypeInitialize error...etc

Comment: ..And add InnerException details with stackTrace. It would be helpful to get specific answer.

Comment: ...and pick appropriate tags eg Emgucv

Comment: does this help? are you using wrong dll version? http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2910